# Network Error when Trying to Connect to Production Backend URL in Expo (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm working on a basic Expo project using React Native, and I'm trying to connect to a production backend URL. The backend is hosted on a production server, and I want to perform a POST request using XMLHttpRequest.
But I get this below error
ERROR  Error: Network request failed

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Prod = () => {
  const apiUrl = 'base_url';
  const headers = {
    LanguageCode: 'en-US',
    subDomain: 'vamscom',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  const body = {
    productKey: 'productKey',
    uniqueKey: 'uniqueKey',
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", apiUrl, true);

      // Set headers
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(headers)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value);
      }

      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            try {
              const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              console.log("Response data:", data);
              // Do something with the data here, as needed
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
              // Handle the error here, if needed
            }
          } else {
            console.error("Network response was not ok");
            // Handle the error here, if needed
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        // Handle the error here, if needed
      };

      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    };

    // Call the function to make the API request
    fetchData();

  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Testing the production API</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Prod;
```

Issue:
I'm facing a "Network Error" when trying to make a POST request to the production backend URL using XMLHttpRequest in my Expo project. The error is not very descriptive, and I'm not sure why the request is failing.

Expected Behavior:
I expect the code to successfully connect to the backend URL and receive a valid response. The backend is hosted on a production server, and it works fine when I access it through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Fetch. Can you use axios instead? Beside I can’t see your base url so I can know if that’s an issue.

Comment: Actually I tried with Axios, Xml and superagent methods too, but nothing seems to be working. Same base url does work in postman. I have not exposed it because It is our corporate URL.